# Display text on Datagridview ComboBox

Tags: vb.net

How can display the text in DatagridView ComboBox which is not in the ComboBox lis?

1- DatagridView ComboBox has been linked to the SQL datatable column and has the following collection items

MD_FF

MM_KJ

DR_MO

DN_OP

WE_FK

XL_LK

QA_ZD

MF_LK

WX_UK

BH_KK

GG_DC

2- the user should add anyone of the droplist or any other combination data from the droplist like (MD_FF|MM_KJ|DN_OP) or any other,

from the following code user was able to that:

```
    Private Sub DatagridView1_CellValidating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) Handles DatagridView1.CellValidating
    If (e.ColumnIndex = DatagridView1.Columns(0).DisplayIndex) Then
        Dim comboBoxColumn As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn = CType(DatagridView1.Columns(0), DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)
        If (Not comboBoxColumn.Items.Contains(e.FormattedValue)) Then
            comboBoxColumn.Items.Add(e.FormattedValue)
            DatagridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = comboBoxColumn.Items(comboBoxColumn.Items.Count - 1)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub DatagridView1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DatagridView1.EditingControlShowing
    If (DatagridView1.CurrentCellAddress.X = DatagridView1.Columns(0).DisplayIndex) Then
        Dim cb As ComboBox = CType(e.Control, ComboBox)
        If (cb IsNot Nothing) Then
            cb.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

3- up to this stage everything work well and the data saved to sql database, but when close the form and open it again, the data which is not matched to the droplist will not display on combobox

the issue here need to show the data which is not matched to drop list like (MD_FF|MM_KJ|DN_OP) on combobox

hope i am clear
and many thanks for help

Comment: Can you be more specific about what this data is and exactly what selections you want to be able to be made and which not? It is possible to bind the column (and implicitly the cells) to one list while using a different list for the editing control, so you see only certain items in the drop-down list when editing a cell. It's hard to be more specific than that with your very generic explanation.

Comment: hello sir, many thanks for reply, i have edit my post, and show all details, hope now more clear, Many thanks

Comment: How exactly are you binding that column?

Comment: through Assign bindingsource on datagrid's datasource property